# MindTouch Core Menu

Tags: iis-7, wiki, mindtouch

I'm trying to accomplish what I consider to be a relatively small tweak to MindTouch Core 10.4. I want to be able to add a menu, pulldown or static, to the existing menu bar. So far I have had no luck. The attached image shows what I am trying to accomplish. The arrow indicates where I want to add a menu.

[image: MindTouch Core Menu]

Answer (score 0):

You could created a new theme for MindTouch, it could make faster and flexible customizing to MindTouch. One article could be found here: http://blog.developer.mindtouch.com/2009/09/02/writing-a-more-flexible-mindtouch-theme/